# Best logic to erase fewer bytes than sector size(minimum erasable size) in flash

Tags: c, embedded, flash-memory

I am using Spansion's flash memory of 16MB. The sector size is 256KB. I am using the flash to read/write/delete 30 byte blocks(structures). I have found in the data sheet of the IC that minimum erasable size is 256KB. One way of deleting a particular block is to

1. Read the sector containing the block to delete into a temporary array.
2. Erase that sector.
3. Delete the required block in temporary array
4. Write back the temporary array into Flash.

I want to ask is there any better alternative logic to this.

Comment: Can't you just rewrite the modified data to the sector without "erasing" it?

Comment: No, writing the data without erasing the location is not possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to erase less than the minimum erasable sector size in flash.

However, there is a typical way to handle invalidating small structures on a large flash sector. Simply add a header to indicate the state of the data in that structure location.

Simple example:

- `0xffff` Structure is erased and available for use.
- `0xa5a5` Structure contains data that is valid.
- `0x0000` Structure contains data that is not valid.

The header will be `0xffff` after erasing. When writing new data to a structure, set the header to `0xa5a5`. When that data is no longer needed, set the header to `0x0000`.

The data won't actually be erased, but it can be detected as invalid. This allows you to wait until the sector is full and then clean up the invalid records and perhaps compact the valid ones.

Comment: The problem of the poster might be more complex, such as he may need to access structures by indices, or the structures themselves refer to each other, however I guess this field is just way more complex than answerable on a SO post. This answer however is a good start to rethink the solution for the overall problem.

Comment: You are saying to modify the header(in the flash) if data is no longer needed or data need to be erased. But to do so, how can I modify the data residing in flash without erasing it?

Comment: @DurgeshTanuku, You can always reprogram bits from 1 to 0 without erasing.  But in order to change any bits from 0 to 1 then you must erase the entire sector.  (Erasing sets all the bits in the sector to 1.)  So, without erasing, you can reprogram a header to all 0 and use that as an indication that the record is no longer valid.

Comment: @Jubatian If the poster wishes to use flash as random-access modifiable memory, his issues will indeed exceed the scope of single SO question. Since his question focused on deleting blocks, I assumed that was his core problem, but did not consider that he might be deleting them in order to write new data there.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, check the device datasheet again. Generally Spansion devices will let you have a 64kB page size instead of 256kB. This may or may not help you, but generally increased granularity will help you.

Secondly, you cannot avoid the "erase before write" cycle where you want to change bits from 0 to 1. However, you can always change bits from 1 to 0 on a byte-by-byte basis.

You can either rethink your current 3-byte structure to see if this is of any use to you, or move to a 32-byte size structure (which is a power of 2 and so slightly more sane IMO). Then, to delete, you can simply set the first byte to 0x00 from 0xFF which a normal erased byte will be set to. That means you'll end up with empty slots.

Like how a garbage collector works, you can then re-organise to move any pages that have deleted blocks on so that you create empty pages (full of deleted blocks). Make sure you move good blocks to a blank page before deleting them from their original page! You can then erase the empty page that was full of deleted, or re-organised blocks.

When you're working with flash memory, you have to think out your read/erase/write strategy to work with the flash you have available. Definitely work it out before you start coding or locking down memory structures, because generally you'll need to reserve at least one byte as a validity byte and usually you have to take advantage of the fact that you can always changes bits that are set to 1 to 0 in any byte at any time without an erase cycle.